# Is there any way to wait for a JMS message to be dequeued in a unit test?

Tags: java, asynchronous, junit, jms, message-queue

I'm writing a spring-boot based project where I have some synchronous (eg. RESTI API calls) and asynchronous (JMS) pieces of code (the broker I use is a dockerized instance of ActiveMQ in case there's some kind of trick/workaround).
One of the problems I'm currently struggling with is: my application receives a REST api call (I'll call it "a sync call"), it does some processing and then sends a JMS message to a queue (async) whose message in then handled and processed (let's say I have a heavy load to perform, so that's why I want it to be async).

Everything works fine when running the application, async messages are enqueued and dequeued as expecting.
When I'm writing tests, (and I'm testing the whole service, which includes the sync and async call in rapid succession) it happens that the test code is too fast, and the message is still waiting to be dequeued (we are talking about milliseconds, but that's the problem).

Basically as soon as i receive the response from the API call, the message is still in the queue, so if, for example I make a query to check for its existence -> ka-boom the test fails because (obviously) it doesn't find the object (that probably meanwhile is being processed and created).

Is there any way, or any pattern, I can use to make my test wait for that async message to be dequeued? I can attach code to my implementation if needed, It's a bachelors degree thesis project.

One obvious solution I'm temporarily using is adding a hundred milliseconds sleep between the method call and the assert section (hoping everything is done and persisted), but honestly I kinda dislike this solution because it seems so non-deterministic to me. Also creating a latch between development code and testing doesn't sound really good to me.

Here's the code I use as an entry-point to al the mess I explained before:

```
public TransferResponseDTO transfer(Long userId, TransferRequestDTO transferRequestDTO) {
        //Preconditions.checkArgument(transferRequestDTO.amount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(userHelper.existsById(userId));
        Preconditions.checkArgument(walletHelper.existsByUserIdAndSymbol(userId, transferRequestDTO.symbol));
        TransferMessage message = new TransferMessage();
        message.userId = userId;
        message.symbol = transferRequestDTO.symbol;
        message.destination = transferRequestDTO.destination;
        message.amount = transferRequestDTO.amount;
        messageService.send(message);

        TransferResponseDTO response = new TransferResponseDTO();
        response.status = PENDING;
        return response;
    }
```

And here's the code that receives the message (although you wouldn't need it):

```
public void handle(TransferMessage transferMessage) {

        Wallet source = walletHelper.findByUserIdAndSymbol(transferMessage.userId, transferMessage.symbol);
        Wallet destination = walletHelper.findById(transferMessage.destination);
        try {
            walletHelper.withdraw(source, transferMessage.amount);
        } catch (InsufficientBalanceException ex) {
            String u = userHelper.findEmailByUserId(transferMessage.userId);
            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
            email.subject = "Insufficient Balance in your account";
            email.to = u;
            email.text = "Your transfer of " + transferMessage.amount + " " + transferMessage.symbol + " has been DECLINED due to insufficient balance.";
            messageService.send(email);
        }
        walletHelper.deposit(destination, transferMessage.amount);
        String u = userHelper.findEmailByUserId(transferMessage.userId);
        EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
        email.subject = "Transfer executed";
        email.to = u;
        email.text = "Your transfer of " + transferMessage.amount + " " + transferMessage.symbol + " has been ACCEPTED.";
        messageService.send(email);
    }
```

Im' sorry if the code sounds "a lil sketchy or wrong" it's a primordial implementation.
I'm willing to write a utility to share with you all if that's the case, but, as you've probably noticed, I'm low on ideas right now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm an ActiveMQ developer working mainly on [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) (the next-gen broker from ActiveMQ). We run into this kind of problem all the time in our test-suite given the asynchronous nature of the broker, and we developed a little [utility class](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-commons/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/utils/Wait.java) that automates & simplifies basic polling operations.

For example, starting a broker is asynchronous so it's common for our tests to include an assertion to ensure the broker is started before proceeding. Using old-school Java 6 syntax it would look something like this:

```java
Wait.assertTrue(new Condition() {
   @Override
   public boolean isSatisfied() throws Exception {
      return server.isActive();
   }
});
```

Using a Java 8 lambda would look like this:

```java
Wait.assertTrue(() -> server.isActive());
```

Or using a Java 8 method reference:

```java
Wait.assertTrue(server::isActive);
```

The utility is quite flexible as the `Condition` you use can test anything you want as long as it ultimately returns a `boolean`. Furthermore, it is deterministic unlike using `Thread.sleep()` (as you noted) and it keeps testing code separate from the "product" code.

In your case you can check to see if the "object" being created by your JMS process can be found. If it's not found then it can keep checking until either the object is found or the timeout elapses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @justin-betram, I've seen the utility class and copy/pasted some ideas. The "final" implementation I made was very similar to the last you mentioned, I've found a very useful utility called [link](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) and used it to specify the condition to fullfill and the maximum amount of time the test should wait before assuming it failed. This way managed not to dirty the production code, at the expense of a few more queries during the tests (but since the db is in memory, and potentially there are no time problems), I consider it a win!